# Can/How I use protractor with chutzpah?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, chutzpah

I've been recently writing unit tests for my angular applications using chutzpah and so far everything is just fine, but now I'm starting to write e2e tests and wanted to use protractor as it's the recommended way of doing e2e in modern angular but I'm not sure on how to integrate both.

I've been searching and couldn't find any example or hint. You can see the setup I'm currently trying in one of my pet proyects here: https://github.com/guerrademitos/MitoPedia

Answer (score 4):

I think you would use Protractor instead of Chutzpah. Chutzpah is a test runner and Protractor is a different test runner. Chutzpah runs tests inside of the PhantomJS headless browser while Protractor is a layer on top of [WebDriverJs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) which is the API on top of Seleniums browser automation framework.

Comment: I may have not get it right, but I thought that Protractor is a testing framework which includes a test runner. What I wanted from it was mostly it's angular digest cycle awareness while keeping Chutzpah's convenience (VS integration, embedded phantomjs, ...)

Thanks a lot for your response, though maybe my question was not generic enough for S.O.